# Php & Session after login to page

Tags: php, session

I have created login page which after user name and pass word is accessing my other pages. But problem is when I am creating session for other pages which I do n't want to be accused without login. I am directed from login page to login again

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $user=$_POST['user'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $query="SELECT * FROM login WHERE user='$user' && password='$password'";
        $data=mysqli_query($db_conn,$query);
        $total=mysqli_num_rows($data);  

        if($total==1)   {
            echo("Login Sucessfull");
            $_SESSION['log']=1;
            header("refresh:3;url=customer_data_ie.php");   
        }
        elseif($total==is_null()){
            echo("Invalid User");
            header("refresh:2;url=login_page_crm.php");
        }
        else{
            echo "Invalid User";
        }
    }
    ?>
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("location:login_page_crm.php");
}else{
    header("location:customer_data_ie.php");
}
```

Comment: change to if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){

and also set value to $_SESSION['user']

Comment: did you set value for `$_SESSION['user']` ?

Comment: Your code is open to SQL Injection attacks. Please use parameters in your query, and preferably instead of directly passing in values from the form/url variables.

Comment: Swati - yes I did

Comment: You have an sql injection problem and you are storing plain text passwords, so you really should start over. About your current problem, it seems you have your logic the wrong way around: You are redirecting to the login page when `$_SESSION['user']` is set, you probably want the reverse: `if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){`. **Edit:** Like @Xun already mentioned I see now...

Comment: if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) not working tried, again going to redirect to login page

Comment: @BhatOvasQayoom I didn’t saw that in your code .. only `$_SESSION['log']` value is set , in your provided code . Try to change your `if-statement` like this —> `if(isset($_SESSION['log'])){ header("location:customer_data_ie.php");
}else{
header("location:login_page_crm.php"); }`

Comment: @Swati I tried this one but still looping back to login page. I wonder can I redefine session in my other pages how it will look !!

Comment: @Swati thanks this worked if(!isset($_SESSION['log'])){
 header("location:login_page_crm.php");